# How do I load balance parallelism in tasks wherein some tasks are very costly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a list of object that needs to processed.  So say that the list is a list of all customers and I need to perform CPU intensive calculation on all of them. Though before and after this calculation I need to fetch and commit data back into a database, so its not purely a CPU task.

so what I do is

`Parallel.ForEach(list, action);`

Where Action is literally

```
1 Fetch customer data
2 Process calculate (time and memory intensive task)
3 Commit back customer data
```

The code used to work good but lately sometimes when **multiple** customers with very a **high number of records** are processed we get system out of memory.

So is there a way to load balance this?  Most of customers are processed quickly, but it is few that take all the resources away.  Can I avoid a few of them running together?

One way I can implement this is by sorting the list based on size and then try and pick first and last item and control parallelism myself but wanting to see what options I have here.

Comment: You could monitor memory usage and pause a couple of customers if it exceeds the limit, but that's nasty.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the parallelism? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jamiec That doesn't really help.  The problem is that the operations are not equivalent.  Some are big, some are tiny.  Lots of tiny operations can all run together, and even a very small number of big items running together is a problem.

Comment: Thats Correct @Servy

Comment: @FCin not sure how to pause a couple of customers ? or you mean i check on total memory usage and put them on wait ? or is there an legit way to pause an iteration/task ?

Comment: You have to implement that yourself - runtime has no idea about cpu and memory requirements of your tasks (until it's too late), so it cannot decide which tasks to run together and which not.

Comment: Frankly you never know *when* a single *action* is gonna grow large enough to run out of memory just by itself. Invest in a streaming approach **now** for large actions.

Comment: @Evk of course Runtime doesn't know about memory requirements, i am looking for a way to handle such scenario, is there any inbuilt operation that i can use to intercept parallel foreach and guide it to pick tasks in a specific order

Comment: @user6144226 what is streaming approach ? can you link me to a resource please ?

Comment: Is it possible to split big customers in multiple chunks? That depends on nature of that calculation you are doing on records.

Comment: @Muds figure out if you need all your customerData always present in memory - or can you get rid of *chunks* after processing them.

Comment: @Evk not really break one into two rather i wanna club bigs with small

Comment: @Muds Yes, we all know that's what you're asking.  But the question to you is can you change your problem such that you break up those bigger operations into multiple smaller operations that individually all require less memory, or find a way to perform whatever computations you need without needing to have the entire data set all in memory at once.  For some operations that's possible, and for some it isn't.

Comment: ok, its not possible to break it any further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you say you have an approximation of the size of the computation before you've actually done it, it simplifies the operation quite a bit.  At that point you simply need a synchronization primitive that doesn't limit the *number* of operations to perform, but instead has some total weight value, and ensures that the sum of all of the currently running operations is less than that specified weight value.  You can then request a given operation runs with a given weight value, and it won't actually run until there is enough unused weight value for it.

There is no existing primitive that does exactly that (Semaphore comes very close, but isn't quite there).  However you can make one fairly easily out of the existing synchronization primitives.

```
public class WeightedSemaphore
{
    public WeightedSemaphore(int totalWeight)
    {
        currentWeight = TotalWeight = totalWeight;
    }

    private ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private int currentWeight;
    public int TotalWeight { get; }
    public int CurrentWeight { get { lock (signal) return currentWeight; } }

    public void Wait(int weight)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (signal)
            {
                if (currentWeight >= weight)
                {
                    currentWeight -= weight;
                    return;
                }
            }

            signal.Reset();
            signal.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void Release(int weight)
    {
        lock (signal)
        {
            currentWeight += weight;
            signal.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can go through each of your operations, ensure that before doing their work they wait on it and provide their "size" value.  From there it'll just take some experimentation to figure out what total weight your current system can support.

Note that a side effect of this is that you'll find that quicker operations tend to get prioritized sooner.  When some space gets freed up, a shorter operation is much more likely to be able to run with what's there, meaning it'll reserve that space before a more expensive operation even gets a shot at running.  This is actually a *desirable* property in many cases, as average response time actually goes *down* when you prioritize the faster operations over the more expensive ones.

Comment: Thanks servy! this actually looks a much cleaner way to have a weight based segregation. will implement this and let you know how it performs.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't semaphore quite there? A SemaphoreSlim is not only really efficient, supports asynchronous waiting,  but also offers the same interface. A Semaphore doesn't mean you have to acquire or release only a single token. The problem here is that it's very easy to get a livelock - expensive operations never get executed because the short and cheap ones keep the resources busy. Fixing that is a much harder problem, but if throughout is high enough might not be a problem.

Comment: @Voo The problem is that it provides no operation that allows you to acquire multiple locks at the same time.  The only way to acquire, say, 10 of a semaphore's 20 locks is to wait 10 times in a loop, but if you do that you can end up with deadlocks.  That pattern also doesn't scale well to larger weight values.  If `Wait` had an overload accepting a number of instances of the lock to take out (`Release` already has such an overload) then it would be suitable.

Comment: @Voo In this particular case starvation of more expensive techniques isn't a problem as there is a fixed number of operations to perform, rather than a constant stream of operations to perform, so the priority on quicker operations is an *advantage*, not a disadvantage.  For a constant stream of operations (where you expect the throughput of that stream to be constantly averaging the machine's capacity, providing the possibility of starvation) would indeed require a more complex scheduling system.  The needs of this question doesn't require that however.

Comment: @Servy Ah the problem of using ints and TimeSpan to denote a timeout, yes I thought `Wait(int)` was the corresponding operation to `Release(int)`.